# ClientEvents tag not working in Infragistics WebImageViewer

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, infragistics

Iam trying automate my WebImageViewer..when the page is loaded the viewer should navigate through the slides/images in it..i've found a few examples on how it's possible, but the best one i found seems to give an exception and i can't seem to find out why. Here's the code and the exception below:-

```
    <ig:WebImageViewer ID="WebImageViewer1" runat="server" BorderColor="#990000" 
    BorderStyle="Groove" 



    style="z-index: 1; left: 221px; top: 300px; position: absolute; height: 576px; width: 720px" 
    BorderWidth="2px">
    <Header Text="CDMS Features" Visible="True">
    </Header>
    <Footer Text="CDMS© is a product of Blue Barracuda Technologies" Visible="True">
    </Footer>
    <Items>
    <ClientEvents Initialize="ivInit" />
    <ScrollAnimations Type="NextItem" />
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/DiagnosisSlider.png" 
            NavigateUrl="http://localhost:9480/Default.aspx" />
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/MedbookSlide.png" />
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/ASKDOCSlider.png" />
    </Items>


</ig:WebImageViewer>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       var imageViewer = null;
       function ivInit(ivCSO)
       {
           imageViewer = ivCSO;
           window.setInterval('imageViewer.navigateNext();', 3000);

       }

</script>
```

The exception i get: Parser Error Message: Infragistics.Web.UI.ListControls.ImageItemCollection must have items of type 'Infragistics.Web.UI.ListControls.ImageItem'. 'ClientEvents' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.

Any ideas? Help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting is because the ClientEvents is within the Items collection and it shouldn't be.  The correct markup is:

```
<ig:WebImageViewer ID="WebImageViewer1" runat="server" BorderColor="#990000" BorderStyle="Groove"
    Style="z-index: 1; left: 221px; top: 300px; position: absolute; height: 576px;
    width: 720px" BorderWidth="2px">
    <Header Text="CDMS Features" Visible="True">
    </Header>
    <Footer Text="CDMS© is a product of Blue Barracuda Technologies" Visible="True">
    </Footer>
    <ClientEvents Initialize="ivInit" />
    <ScrollAnimations Type="NextItem" />
    <Items>
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/DiagnosisSlider.png" NavigateUrl="http://localhost:9480/Default.aspx" />
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/MedbookSlide.png" />
        <ig:ImageItem ImageUrl="~/Styles/ASKDOCSlider.png" />
    </Items>
</ig:WebImageViewer>
```